# Google Plus One button: Strange behaviour

Tags: google-plus

On this page (http://www.nicofauser.de/cartoons/item/cartoon-kw26-2015/) there's a Google +1 below the cartoon. If the counter shows 0 and I share the cartoon, the counter jumps to 1. But when I reload the page after some minutes, the counter shows 2. When I go to my Google+ profile and delete the shared cartoon and go back to the website and reload the page after some minutes, the counter shows 32. I've checked this for 3 different cartoons, always the same.
What's happening there?

I've implemented the Google +1 button like this:

```
<div class="googleplus">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer>{lang:'de'}</script>
  <div class="g-plusone" data-href="http://www.nicofauser.de/cartoons/item/cartoon-kw26-2015/"> </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I can't replicate the zero count. It's always 32 for me.

Comment: Damn, this changed since yesterday. But this obviously is also an error. Why does every page, in spite of different  urls, have the same count?

Comment: I'm not sure what's going on. It looks like the +1 buttons are independently toggled but showing the total number of +1's. Maybe Google is running a test of some sort.